# Unable to Initialize TDSE object. Error Code: 0x80040302 (-2147220734)

Tags: windows-server-2003, tridion

I am setting up Tridion R 5.3 content Manger server on Windows Server 2003. My Windows server is not having Active Directory service enabled. The Impersonation user that I have set in Tridion Configuration Manager is

```
WORKGROUP\mtsuser
```

since the 2003 server is not under any domain. Now whenever I try accessing console on `//localhost/` and enter my credentials for mts user. The following error is shown with Message on Console reading as

```
You don't have permission to access R 5.3 contact Administrator.

Event Type: Warning 
Event Source: Kernel
Event Category: Security
Event ID: 200
Date: 2/15/2013
Time: 2:11:23 PM
User: WORKGROUP\mtsuser
Computer: WORKGROUP
Description:
Unable to Initialize TDSE object.
Access is denied for the user WORKGROUP\mtsuser.
Error Code:
0x80040302 (-2147220734)
Call stack:
SystemBLST.GetUserContext
SystemBLST.IBLSecurityST_GetUserContext
TDSE.Initialize
```

Comment: shouldn't that be SERVER_NAME\MTSUser rather than WORKGROUP\MTSUser?

Comment: WORKGROUP is the Server name and mtsuser is having admin rights and user rights both.

Comment: is this user listed in the TRUSTEES table?

Comment: This I am not able to say but mtsuser is having admin rights that I can see.

Comment: Bart please clarify me whether the Trustees Table exist on a Server on which Directory services are not enabled and is not configured under a domain. The one which i am working on is a standalone server with no directory service configured and no domain.

Comment: Hi Bart it is breaking at the component level and to access database I have configured the user in Tridion Configuration Manager Snapin. That user exists in Trustees Table I checked in Tridion DB

Comment: Same question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/14959127/unable-to-initialize-tdse-object-error-code-0x80040302-2147220734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if you understood anything of what we said on both Serverfault and stackoverflow, so I'll try again.

- MTSUser: A Windows account that Tridion uses to run "the system"
- TCMDBUser: A Database account that is used by "the system" to access the Tridion Database
- `You don't have permission to access R 5.3`: An error message saying you're not allowed to access the system.

The Tridion CM database has a TRUSTEES table in it. This TRUSTEES table contains the names of the users that are allowed to use Tridion. Make sure your MTSUser account is listed in this table, with the correct machine name (WORKGROUP\MTSUser in your case).

Since it looks like you got a copy of the 5.3 db and were told to "just get it to work", these are the various steps needed:

1. Make sure the copy of the database really includes everything. I'm not joking.
2. Change the TRUSTEES table to have the correct MTSUser name (including machine or domain name)
3. While you're on the TRUSTEES table, add a user for yourself, so that you don't have to login with MTSUser
4. Run the installer, point it to the right database, and good luck.

Since this is Tridion 5.3, a version that is almost 6 years old, I doubt you'll find many people that still understand the installation process well enough to help you much more than this.